# How to assign a value from a pointer to a variable permanently

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I am building a very rudimentary disassembler for the Z80 processor. My program first reads 8-bit instructions from a binary file and stores them in a vector `bytes`. That vector is passed to function `disassemble(vector<int>& bytes)`, which iterates through the `bytes` vector and parses each byte(s) to it's (their) corresponding instruction(s). Each instruction is added to vector `assembly`.

```
void disassemble(std::vector<int>& bytes)
{
    std::vector<char*> assembly;
    char instruction[20];
    int xx, yy;
    for (auto it = bytes.begin(); it != bytes.end(); ++it) {
        switch (*it)
        {
            case 0x00: // nop
                assembly.push_back("nop");      
                break;
            case 0x01: // ld bc, $xxyy
                yy = *(++it);
                xx = *(++it);
                sprintf_s(instruction, "ld bc, $%02X%02X",xx,yy);
                assembly.push_back(instruction);
                break;
            default:
                assembly.push_back("Instruction not implemented.");
                break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "instructions: " << assembly.size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < assembly.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << assembly.at(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have two instructions implemented so far:

- 0x00: nop
- 0x01: ld bc, $xxyy (where yy and xx represent the next two bytes, respectively)

For example, the following binary code:
`00 01 0D C9 00 00 01 D5 C5 01 05 5C 00 00`
should disassemble to (comments added by me):

```
nop ; 00
ld bc, $C90D; 01 0D C9
nop ; 00
nop ; 00
ld bc, $C5D5 ; 01 D5 C5
ld bc, $5C05 ; 01 05 5C
nop ; 00
nop ; 00
```

Actual Output:

```
instructions: 8
nop
ld bc, $5C05
nop
nop
ld bc, $5C05
ld bc, $5C05
nop
nop
```

As you can see, when the code is finished, all of the 0x01 instructions are parsed as `ld bc, $5C05`. During debugging, I have watched the `assembly` vector populate, and the `ld bc, $C90D` is interpreted correctly. However, when the next ld instruction is parsed, the previous one is updated to `ld bc, $C5D5`. The same thing happens when the final ld instruction is parsed.

I'm guessing this has to do with xx and yy being assigned to an iterator which continuously updates with each new ld instruction. How do I increment the iterator without updating the elements of `assembly`? I would like to stick with iterators instead of using `for(int i=0; i<bytes.size(); i++)` since I have never used them before and enjoy learning new things. But if that's what must be done, then so be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every entry in the vector is the same -- a pointer to `instruction`. If you want each entry in the vector to be different, you have to `push_back` *different* values.

The most logical fix is to change `assembly` to be a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: That was not the culprit I was expecting! I changed ```assembly``` to a ```std::vector<std::string>``` and added the following: ```assembly.push_back((std::string) instruction);``` and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Previous code simply assigns each ld instruction to be the same char array ('instruction'). Whatever instruction you last wrote into that buffer will be the same for each ld instruction you insert (because they all refer to the same instruction). A simple-ish fix would be something along these lines....

```
std::vector<std::string> assembly;
```

However, since I've written my own z80 assemblers & disassemblers in the past, I'd recommend taking a quick pause, and getting to know the instruction set better!

The instruction set is best viewed as a table, e.g. http://clrhome.org/table/

If you look at the instructions 0x40 -> 0x47 for example, you'll notice that they are strikingly similar to 0x48 -> 0x4F (as are 0x50 -> 0x57, etc, etc). Rather than having a switch statement of 256 vars (plus tables for the extended op codes, and undefined op codes), try to identify those repeating patterns, and process accordingly. i.e.

```cpp
const char* const registers[] = {"B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "L", "(HL)", "A"};

void printLD(uint8_t op)
{
  assert( op >= 0x40 && op <= 0x7F );
  printf("LD %s, %s\n", registers[(op >> 4) - 4], registers[op & 0xF]);
}
void printADD(uint8_t op)
{
  assert( op >= 0x80 && op <= 0x87 );
  printf("ADD A, %s\n", registers[op & 0xF]);
}
void printADC(uint8_t op)
{
  assert( op >= 0x88 && op <= 0x8F );
  printf("ADC A, %s\n", registers[op & 0xF]);
}
```

You'll quickly notice the instructions are organised in blocks of 8, so you'be better better off switching on the first nibble, and deferring to a function afterwards, e.g.

```cpp
void printOp(uint8_t op)
{
  uint8_t hi = op >> 4;
  uint8_t lo = op & 4;
  switch(hi)
  {
  case 0x4:
  case 0x5:
  case 0x6:
  case 0x7: printLD(op); break;
  case 0x8: if(lo < 8) printADD(op) else printADC(op); break;
  }
}
```

It will save you a hell of a lot of time in the long run, and make it far easier to debug. (IIRC there are around 1400 or so opcodes in the Z80 instruction set, and that will make for some pretty grim switch statements!)